# Understanding what is happening when Magento initialises a module

Tags: magento

I am trying to understand how what is happening in my config, when I set up a new module. To create a module called Ts_Wo I need to add

app/code/etc/modules/Ts_Wo.xml

```
<config>
   <modules>
      <Ts_Wo>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
      </Ts_Wo>
   </modules>
</config>
```

And need to add

app/code/local/Ts/Wo/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Ts_Wo>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Ts_Wo>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <wo>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Ts_Wo</module>
                <frontName>wo</frontName>
            </args>
        </wo>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

from here I go to the magento admin panel system->configuration->advanced to check if the module is enabled.

This has all worked fine until I spotted that I had created two modules Ts_Wo and Ts_Woo. Obviously I corrected the typo (which I found in modules node of config.xml) and I was back to one module

My questions:

1- I thought Magento required both of these files to create the module?

2- If it doesn't why do I create the two files?

2a- If it does how is it two different modules were displayed when I would have expected no module to be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "module" in Magento is a fuzzy, ill-defined concept. Depending on what the developer provides, the application/code will realize any classes and configuration which are part of the module in varying ways. For example, create a class `Ts_Wo_Model_Foo` at *`app/code/local/Ts/Wo/Model/Foo.php`* and then instantiate it in the application somewhere via `new Ts_Wo_Model_Foo`. It's a class which could be part of a module, yet the module itself doesn't properly exist in the application.
2. There *should be* two separate configuration XML files so that the module's declaration XML (in *`app/etc/modules/`*, which *is* part of the overall configuration DOM) can be used to control whether the module's configuration XML (e.g. *`app/code/local/Ts/Wo/etc/config.xml`*) should be merged, and in what order (based on `<depends>`). Setting the `<active>` flag to `false` will prevent the module config from being merged.

   2a. The display in the admin (System > Configuration > Advanced) is notoriously deceiving. One, this group is used to disable module *output*. Two, the "modules" listed in this group are simply derived from all nodes under the `modules` configuration DOM xpath, nothing more, nothing less. ***Even "modules" with `<active>` flag set to false will appear in this list.***

Comment: @benmarks Only adding to the fuzziness, but I never saw the app/etc/modules files as **part** of the module.  Those are more Magento configuration files to tell it which module to load.

Comment: @AlanStorm - That's the proper way to think of them. Unfortunately they can be (and have been) used to sore main module configuration.